# Cannot set property to null

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML, CSS and JS file. Everything working perfectly except my console is showing me a message "Cannot set property 'textContent' of null".

I have already tried surrounding the code with `window.onload` but still had no luck. [html code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duICp.png)

[image: Error message]

game.js

```
var colors = [
  'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
  'rgb(255, 255, 0)',
  'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
  'rgb(0, 255, 255)',
  'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
  'rgb(255, 0, 255)'
];

var squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
var pickedColor = colors[3];
var display = document.getElementById('colorDisplay');
display.textContent = pickedColor;

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  // ADD INITIAL COLORS TO SQUARES
  squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];

  // ADD EVENTLISTENERS TO SQUARES
  squares[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.style.backgroundColor);
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Agent Color</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="game.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> color game</h1>
<div id="container">
   <div class="square"></div>
   <div class="square"></div>
   <div class="square"></div>
   <div class="square"></div>
   <div class="square"></div>
   <div class="square"></div>
</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: when is this code called?

Comment: What happens when you just print colors[3]?

Comment: try `console.log(document.getElementById("colorDisplay"))` it's probably null

Comment: When I click, the colors do print.

Comment: Is there an html element which ID is **colorDisplay** ?

Comment: Yeap. Let me add that HTML code too.

Comment: Waw... what a fight! ahaha (at)messerbill and OP competing on who is the fastest changer :D - @Usama, please, next time: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - welcome and good luck.

Comment: add the HTML to the question - not as an image please

Comment: also, your script should be before the closing body tag - not after

Comment: By putting game.js in your header, you are calling your JS before your HTML.

Comment: you also include game.js twice

Comment: Yeap thanks to @Nosajimiki. I used the script tag twice.

Comment: Im a newbie here and was in a hurry to post the question and made alot of changes later. Sorry for the inconvenice guys and thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 3):

`var display=document.getElementById("colorDisplay")` - this is `null` because (at least at the execution time) there is no element with the id of `colorDisplay`.

If you are sure that you have such an element in your code ensure that your DOM Content is already loaded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: how can you be sure without seeing OP HTML?

Comment: i do not have to see the OPs full code - like i said, either the element does simply not exist, or it has not been loaded yet

Comment: see latest comment on post

Comment: @messerbill is right, this error would only occur if the element does not exist or does not exist yet.  Most likely, this is a case of needed an onload function or he needs to declare his HTML before his JS.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is an element with Id colorDisplay in the DOM and ready when the js code runs. For example put the js at the end of the body container to make sure, the DOM is ready.

Comment: Put it inside the body container and remove it from the head container.